# Magento : How To Remove Simple Product From Quote in Observer

Tags: product, event-observer, magento-1, quote, bundle

I am using this event: `sales_quote_save_after`
This is my function code:

```
public function myFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $o){
    $quote = $o->getEvent()->getQuote();
}
```

I have `simple products` and `bundle products`. I would like to remove only simple products. How can I do that?

Thx

Comment: This will require you removing items from the quote, then re-saving the quote which will trigger a `sales_quote_save_after` event again. This is dangerous grounds for an infinite loop unless you're careful. Your best bet is to remove the items before saving the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
 $quote = $o->getEvent()->getQuote();
 $quoteItems=$quote->getAllItems();
 if(count($quoteItems)>0){
    foreach($quoteItems as $oneItem){
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($oneItem->getProductId());
        $productType=$product ->getTypeId();
        if($productType=='simple'){
          $quote->removeItem($oneItem->getId());
        }
    }
   $quote->collectTotals()->save();
  }
```